# DjangoCMS / Django - detecting if current page is child

Tags: django, if-statement, navigation, parent-child, django-cms

I'm looking to customise the sub_menu.html template with DjangoCMS, and have currently got the following code for the menu:

```
{% if children %}
<div class="unit subnav">
<h3>{% page_attribute "menu_title" %}</h3>
<ul>
    {% for child in children %}
        <li class="{% if child.selected %}on{% endif %}{% if child.ancestor %}ancestor{% endif %}{% if child.sibling %}sibling{% endif %}{% if child.descendant %}descendant{% endif %}">
            <a href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ child.get_menu_title }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

So basically, this detects if the page has children, and then adds the sub navigation if children of this page exist.

So far, so good.

My problem is that when I navigate to the child pages themselves - the menu disappears, so I'd like to detect if the page is a "child" below level 1. This should stop all pages having a nav (because they're all children of the homepage I presume) but should allow those below the main level of navigation to have the menu appear.

If anybody can lend a hand or point me in the right direction, that would be brilliant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it might not make sense to people, but I was able to get to the bottom of this with the following if statement within my subnav template...

```
{% if children or request.current_page.level > 0 %} subnav in here {% endif %}
```

Comment: Six years later still usefull! Solved my problem. Thanks a lot for the question and the answer.

Comment: looks like in cms 3.6, all treebeard related things are in the `node` property of a page object, for example `request.current_page.node.get_children` (or get_depth, for the level equivalent). new, but also cool, as you have the complete treebeard API at hand.